# FMDatabase Resultset

Tags: ios, sqlite, fmdb

FMDatabase *database = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];
    [database open];

```
FMResultSet *results = nil;
results=[database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM CLINIQDB"];

while([results next])
{
    countryArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [countryArr addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"countryNames"]];

}

    NSLog(@"The country arr %@",countryArr);
[database close];
```

Actually I have 10 country names but contryArr showing only last value for example
my countries are {India,Australia,..........,Russia};

countryArr have only Russia in it.

what's wrong with my code.

Comment: @SrinivasReddy check my answer. You are initialising you countrtArr every time. Initialise it before of while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise your array before of while loop

```
FMResultSet *results = nil;
results=[database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM CLINIQDB"];

countryArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while([results next])
{

    [countryArr addObject:[results stringForColumn:@"countryNames"]];

}

NSLog(@"The country arr %@",countryArr);
[database close];
```